# javaScripts in web browser control in windows application

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am using a web browser control in my vb.net application where I am navigating to http://blsspainvisa.com/svas/chat/.  The site opens well in all the browsers but gives error in control.

WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://blsspainvisa.com/svas/chat/")

I am new in handling web pages and application.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I answered a similar question before. Please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160333/iwebbrowser2-seemingly-not-executing-javascript/41092206#41092206

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem in webbrowser, is this use an old version of IE. I think IE7. If this web site use new versions of JS frameworks it will display several error. Please try with chromium https://cefsharp.github.io/